# How to start SQL Server from Batch file?

Tags: service, command-line

I'm trying to start SQL Server Express from command line using the following command:

> net start MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS

But I get this error:

> System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.

I have administrator privilege and my OS is Windows 7.

Comment: Is it "my account is in the administrator group" or "my command line is running with administrator privileges"? These are different.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen "my account is in the administrator group"

Comment: You also have to start the command line with admin privileges. Just being in the group doesn't give permission to manage services.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks for your comment. That was my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @SamiKuhmonen my problem was solved.

I created batch file (named start sqlserver.bat) conatins the following command:

`net start MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS`

I created a shortcut to my batch file.

And run it as administrator like in this
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFUJj.jpg)

Comment: To set the shortcut to run as administrator right click on the shortcut, select shortcut tab, advanced > check "run as administrator". Tested this on Windows 10. The name of the service can be found by running Services from Start Menu. Right click on the service name > properties > general tab > service name can be found at the top

Answer (score 0):

Run Registry Editor (RegEdit).
Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
Right click on   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, and select Permissions .

Click on the Advanced button.

In “Advanced Security Settings” dialog window, go to the Owner tab.
Select and highlight the currently logged on user name or Administrators group (if user is a member of Administrators” in the Change owner to: box.
Select the tick the check box for Replace owner on subcontainers and objects option, and click OK.

Back in “Permissions” dialog window, click on Add… button.
Enter everyone in the Enter the object names to select text box, and click on the Check Names button.

Hope it helps!!!

If there is error with the user ID entered, correct the error. If there is no error found, click the OK button.

Back in “Permissions” dialog window, select and highlight the newly added user name in Group or user names: section, and tick the checkbox for Allow access right next to Full Control in the Permissions for Everyone section.

Answer (score 0):

simply create the batch file as eg.bat
and it's content as :start ssms

Comment: For a relatively old question, please provide some sample code and include steps. Use other answers on this post as reference if needed!